# Categorical Morita equivalence implies equivalence of module categories?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, higher-category-theory, braided-tensor-categories, morita-equivalence, morita-theory

Classically, two rings $R$ and $S$ are Morita equivalent if and only if any of the following is true

1. ($R$-Mod) $\simeq$ ($S$-Mod).
2. $S \simeq Hom_R(M,M)$, where $M$ is a finitely generated projective generator in ($R$-Mod).

A tensor category is a categorical analogue of a ring. Two tensor categories $C$ and $D$ are said to be categorical Morita equivalent if there is an exact $C$-module category $M$ and a tensor equivalence [1, Definition 7.12.17]

$$ D^{op} \simeq C^\star_M. $$

This definition resembles the second condition in the classical case. Thus my **question**:

> In this case, do $C$ and $D$ have equivalent categories of module categories?

**Reference**

- [1] Tensor Categories-[Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych, and Ostrik]

Comment: There’s some technical issues you need to be careful about.  Firstly, the collection of module categories forms a 2-category!  Second you need to be careful about how you build that 2-category (probably you want the right exact functors).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is Theorem 7.12.16 in [1]. In fact these are 2-equivalent (as the categories of modules are 2-categories).

**Theorem 7.12.16.** Let $M$ be a faithful exact module category over $C$. The $2$-functor

$$
(7.36)   \quad\quad N \mapsto Fun_{C}(M,N): Mod(C) \to Mod((C_M^\star)^{op})
$$

is a $2$-equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Tricky! It's stated before the definition of categorical Morita equivalence. I've added the statement in your answer. I need some time to review however, as there is an extra condition ("faithful") in the theorem.